# prove trigonometry identity for $\sin\alpha+\sin2\alpha+\sin3\alpha+...+\sin N\alpha$, whithout using induction

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

prove that:

$$\sin \alpha+\sin2\alpha+\sin3\alpha+...+\sin N\alpha = \frac{\sin\frac{N\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{(N+1)\alpha}{2}}{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}$$
without $\sum$

Comment: I would try induction!

Comment: Should it be a $N$ in your right formula?

Comment: yes N as any number